# onclick() is not working when using it in tag inside a js string

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to convert strings starting with '#' and '@' to a clickable link and for that I'm doing a regex to replace that word with html  tag and adding onclick function inside it to perform the operation by calling the search function. I'm using 'html-react-parser' to parse that in the render part. That is converting the text to button but it is not calling the search() function when I click it on. I can't understand how can I fix that? Is there anyway to fix that or any better approach?

The data I'm trying to convert is in JSON format which has three different field.

Data sample:

```
{date:"2014-06-01 04:27:08", text:"Bob Newhart, Master of the One-Sided Conversation t.co/xmdtl25WyD via @nytnow", user_id:"nytimes"}
```

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import client from './Credentials';
import '../App.css';
import Linkify from 'react-linkify';
import Parser from 'html-react-parser';

export default class Search extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {results: []};
    }

    // const Autolinker = require( 'autolinker' );

    search(string){
        client.search({
            index: 'tweet',
            type: 'tweet',
            size: 1000,
            body: {
                query: {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {"match": {"text": string}},
                            {"match": {"user_id": string}},
                            {"match": {"date": string}}
                        ]
                    }
                },
            }
        }, (error, response, status) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log("search error: " + error)
            }
            else {
                console.log("--- Response ---");
                console.log(response);
                console.log("--- Hits ---");
                response.hits.hits.forEach(function (hit) {
                    let re1 = new RegExp("((#|@)([a-z0-9]+))", "g");

                    hit._source.text = hit._source.text.replace(re1, ("<button onclick={this.search($&)}>$&</button>"));
                    this.setState({results: this.state.results.concat([hit._source])})
                }.bind(this)
                );

            }
            // console.log(this.state.results);
        })
    }

    handleKeyPress = (event) => {
        if(event.key === 'Enter'){
            event.preventDefault();
            const search_query = event.target.value;
            this.state.results=[];
            this.search(search_query);

        }
    };

    render() {

        return(
            <Linkify>
                <div>
                    <input className={"search-bar"} type="text" onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress.bind(this)}>
                    </input>

                    <div>{this.state.results.map((results, index) => (
                        <p key={index} className={"result"}><span className={"date"}>{results.date}</span> <span>&nbsp;</span>
                            <span className={"user_id"}>{results.user_id}</span> <span>&nbsp;</span>
                            <span>{Parser(results.text)}</span></p>
                    ))}</div>


                </div>
            </Linkify>

        );

    }

}
```

Comment: try onClick not onclick

Comment: Still not working. That's not even reading css class too.

Comment: how about `onClick={()=>this.search($&)}` ?

Comment: It's printing "this.search(@nytnow)}>@nytnow" but not calling the function. Giving warning that it needs to be Ivalue in '()' this bracket.

Comment: its printing where? Does the button gets rendered? Do you see your button on the page?

Comment: button is getting rendered and this is "this.search(@nytnow)}>@nytnow" button's name.

Comment: open discussion :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163599/discussion-between-nilesh-kumar-and-nicholas).

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you are trying to parse string as javascript code. This isn't normally possible, and is considered dangerous. If you want to do so, [this issue](https://github.com/wrakky/react-html-parser/issues/8) has some insights

change the button to

hit._source.text = hit._source.text.replace(re1, ("" + $& + ""));

```
Parser(results, { transform: () => this.htmlParserTransformer })
```

and

```
import {convertNodeToElement} from "react-html-parser"
  htmlParserTransform = (node, index) => {
    if (node.type == "tag" && node.name == "button") { // button tag
      const {id} = node.attribs // extract the actual url
      return (
        <button 
          onClick={() => this.search(id)} // click 
          >
            {convertNodeToElement (node, index, this.htmlParserTransform)}
          </span>
        </a>
      )
    }
```

PS: this code isn't tested, but I hope I'm pointing you in the right direction.